# glob_recurse generate error in cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a library with several source files under several directories. I want to write a cmake in a way that it add all of them to project without asking to writ them separately.

I am using this line in my cmake:

```
FILE(GLOB_RECURSE ALL_Lib_CPP_SRCS  src/Library/ *.cpp)
add_library(MyLibrary STATIC ALL_Lib_CPP_SRCS)
```

but generate msvc project doesn't have all files included and I am getting this message when I am running cmake:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:49 (add_library):
Cannot find source file:

ALL_Lib_CPP_SRCS
Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp .hxx .in .txx
```

What is the problem with this cmake?

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
FILE(GLOB_RECURSE ALL_Lib_CPP_SRCS "src/Library/*.cpp")
add_library(MyLibrary STATIC ${ALL_Lib_CPP_SRCS})
```

In my opinion, it's better that you defined manually the sources:

```
set (_SOURCES source3.cpp source2.cpp source1.cpp main.cpp)
# now use ${_SOURCES}
```

this way, you can know the exact order of compilation...sometimes the order is important

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax according to the manual is:

```
 file(GLOB_RECURSE variable [RELATIVE path] [FOLLOW_SYMLINKS] [globbing expressions]...)
```

I suspect you're either missing `RELATIVE`:

```
FILE(GLOB_RECURSE ALL_Lib_CPP_SRCS RELATIVE "src/Library/" "*.cpp")
```

Or you have an extra space in the globbing expression:

```
FILE(GLOB_RECURSE ALL_Lib_CPP_SRCS "src/Library/*.cpp")
```

I suspect the second option above is what you want. The quotes are optional, but I would recommend their use, as it makes the line easier to read IMO.

---

The second issue is that you need a `${}` when you reference the variable:

```
add_library(MyLibrary STATIC ${ALL_Lib_CPP_SRCS})
```